# Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in my Linux cPanel server?

Tags: php, mysql, whm

I have included the `php.ini` file in folder `public_html` and pasted the mysqli extension. Still the problem is not solved. I updated my PHP and MySQL to the latest possible versions. My server is a dedicated server and not a shared one. I don't want to use the old MySQL function.

#### Versions

MY PHP version: 5.4.33
MySQL version: 5.5.45-cll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a test page and print the `phpinfo()` and check if mysqli is enabled or not in your system.
2. If installed and disable then enable that using php.ini
3. If not installed in your system then install

   > **Mysqli Installation ** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have tried and figured it out. I have checked your reply, after it worked. Any way's thank you so much mitul for replying.